# Обработка события клика мыши, при нажатой клавише на клавиатуре WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Нужно обработать клик мыши с зажатой клавишей, к примеру CTRL, по элементу управления Кнопка.
Я так понимаю, обрабатываться всё же будем в обработчике клика и там проверять, нажата ли нужная клавиша на клавиатуре.
Только вот вопрос, как можно проверить, нажата ли клавиша?

Comment: Эти данные можно получить из класса [`Keyboard` и свойства `Modifiers`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.keyboard.modifiers?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Input_Keyboard_Modifiers)

Comment: Попробовал  только что через метод  Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl), сработало

Comment: @ヒミコ, я понял, но мне это по сути и нужно, чтобы одна функциоя сработала при нажатой клавише, а при отпущенной клавише и клике - выполнялась другая функция

Comment: @ヒミコ, хорошо, а если у меня сразу при входе в обработчик стоит условная конструкция плана  if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl)){ }, врятли я смогу в реальности отпустить клавишу раньше, чем зайду в тело условной конструкции)

Answer (score 0):

```
     private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           if(Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("function 1"); // ЛКМ при зажатой клавиши CTRL
            }
           else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("function 2"); // ЛКМ без зажатой клавиши CTRL
            }
        }
```